# Filter Eloquent morphTo relation based on column in other table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, table-relationships

I have an Eloquent model, that morphs to other Eloquent models, like this:

```
<?php

class Message extends Eloquent {

    public function message()
    {
        return $this->morphTo('message');
    }

}
```

The reason being, the application has many different types of messages. I know it’s not the most elegant of approaches, but it’s what I’ve been lumbered with by the previous developer.

So, my issue is: I need to only return `Message` instances, where the `state` column in the morphed-to message table matches a value. I have this query scope method in my `Message` model class:

```
public function scopeDeclinedMessages($query)
{
    return $query->with(array('message' => function ($q)
    {
        $q->where('state', '=', MessageState::DECLINED);

    }));
}
```

However, this doesn’t work, as it still returns `Messages` where the `state` in the morphed-to table *doesn’t* match the declined state.

For transparency, `MessageState::DECLINED` is a value of `2`, but I’m getting messages back where the morphed-to table `state` column equals `0`.

Comment: Show the code, where you execute the query and the query as well (`DB::getQueryLog()` for example)

Comment: @deczo I don’t execute the query, Eloquent’s fluent query builder is used e.g. `$messages->declinedMessages();`

Comment: Exactly, you get wrong results, according to your question, so show that code.

Comment: @deczo I don’t think I follow. I’ve given the code. I call my `declinedMessages()` scope, on the models listed above in the question.

Comment: Well, my guess would be bug in `Eloquent`, since polymorphic relationships are buggy. I don't think you can do what you want, because `where` set in closure will be ignored. So check the queries run and you will know.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3986